# Connect a bare Android on a developer board to PC via USB

Tags: usb, android, file-transfer, bare-metal

I have a **bare** android and I plan to install `google play` service on it. I found the `apk` file but I need to transfer this file on the device.

When I plug my usb, no drive appears in the file explorer. How can I transfer files via USB?

My limitations:

- I have a bare android on an embedded development board. This is not a mobile phone.
- I have no Ethernet, no wifi, no bluetooth.
- I have no google play store.
- I have no Gmail, Dropbox, etc. (and no internet either.)
- I have no access to Recovery Mode (as there is no button for that).

My Device Manager detects the USB as a `USB Composite Device`.

In the *Settings* -> *Storage* there is no option `Media device (MTP)`. 
Bare Android is very limited.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: How did you get android on there in the first place?

Comment: @Moab, Factory installation.

Comment: What storage device is the OS on?